# Android Firebase authentication: IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase authentication in my Android application so when I press the button login when the text fields email and password are empty my application crash. I used Firebase version 10.0.1, This my code :

```
        button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              final String  email_et = mail_login_et.getText().toString();
              final String  password_et = pass_login_et.getText().toString();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_et, password_et)
         .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 Log.d("LOGINACT", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                 } else {
                     // startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));*
                     Log.w("LOGINACT", "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                 }
                 }
         });
            }
    });
```

and this is the error log:

```
            E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzdv(Unknown Source)
                     at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                     at com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:83)
                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.358ms
         E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.esprit.couverture4g, PID: 3127
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzdv(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
                  at com.esprit.couverture4g.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:83)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You're passing in `null` or an empty string as the email address or as the password. The solution is to handle empty values in your code, probably making the user aware that they must enter a value.

Comment: It seems that one of the Strings (email or password) you're passing is null or empty. Try to log both values to see where the problem is